# Unable to see the attributes for the custom block created

Tags: block-editor

I installed create-block from

```
npx @wordpress/create-block  post-group
```

**block.json**

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schemas.wp.org/trunk/block.json",
    "apiVersion": 2,
    "name": "create-block/post-group",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "title": "Post Group",
    "category": "widgets",
    "icon": "smiley",
    "attributes": {
        "title":  {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "content":  {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "showContent": {
          "type": "boolean"
        }
      },
    "description": "Example static block scaffolded with Create Block tool.",
    "supports": {
        "html": true
    },
    "textdomain": "post-group",
    "editorScript": "file:./index.js",
    "editorStyle": "file:./index.css",
    "style": "file:./style-index.css"
}
```

But I dont see the attributes
[image]

Basically i want to set

a. dropdown, where user can select latest, category, tag, custom

b. dropdown to select max posts

c. dropdown to select posts per row

d. style to be applied per post

I am expecting an output as in heading block right hand side.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Attributes just define a "schema" of sorts which informs WordPress which persistent data is associated with a block, and how WordPress should parse it from the block's saved markup/[block grammar](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/contributors/code/grammar/). WordPress makes no assumptions about if or how a UI should be constructed to expose attributes to the end-user - you must construct the UI yourself.

The exception to this may be [Block Supports](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/block-tutorial/block-supports-in-static-blocks/), which can be used to register certain core capabilities for a block that may come with some limited automatic UI - adding `"colors"` entries will provide a color picker for each entry and store the selections in a `style` attribute, for instance.

For constructing the UI in other cases, the standalone React components provided by [the `@wordpress/components`](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-components/) package are more than sufficient for most use-cases (but if not, there is nothing stopping you from using React components from third-party sources!). Previews, docs, and examples for the components can be found over on [the Gutenberg Storybook instance](https://wordpress.github.io/gutenberg/). Docs can also be found in the [Components Reference Guide](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/components/). A couple other components which are more dependent on WordPress and as such are not suitable for inclusion in the library of standalone components reside in their own packages, such as [`@wordpress/rich-text`](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-rich-text/).

Any components returned by your `edit` function will be displayed within the block. [Rendering components in the sidebar](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/block-tutorial/block-controls-toolbar-and-sidebar/) is accomplished by wrapping the components in `@wordpress/block-editor`'s `<InspectorControls>` component.

Some good general instruction and advice can be found in the [Block Editor Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor)'s [Create a Block Tutorial](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/getting-started/create-block/).